# Intersection of Three Periodic Lines

Tags: functions

This question is related to my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178729/length-of-vector-formed-by-three-triangle-waves), but on rethinking the problem I have come up with another solution that would be also acceptable.

I have three broken lines.  Each has a constant gap of length $a$, a constant fill of length $b$ between them, and an offset $c$.  Each line is something like $\lbrace t \mid a k < t+c < (a+b)k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$ In the diagram below, I have plotted three example lines with respect to $t$.

In the diagram below, the areas where all three lines overlap is highlighted.  I am interested in the first $t\ge0$ where this happens (perhaps that can be found from a general form of the lines' intersection).  The lines plotted (top to bottom) have constants $a,b,c$ in pixels: $(60,72,-51)$, $(36,12,-4)$, and $(41,17,-18)$.  The first $t$ satisfying all three lines is 196, so that would be the answer.

[image]

Basically, I'd be looking for the set intersection of the lines, as expressed above.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.  Another way might be to convolve three rectangle waves, and look at the result.  Thoughts?

Comment: In general, I believe describing the intersection is a very hard dynamical systems problem, particularly if the ratios $b/c$ are independent over $\mathbb Q$ for the different lines.

Comment: Are the lines always at a constant value? If so, then add all three of them: $f(t) = l_1(t)+l_2(t)+l_3(t)$. The intersecting areas will be the values of $t$ for which $f(t)$ is at its maximum.

Comment: Yes; the lines' $a$, $b$, and $c$ values remain constant.  By add, I assume you mean add some equivalent rectangle waves, and find where their sum is first three.

Answer (score 0):

If the first complete overlap usually comes as early as in your example, you don't have to worry about efficiency. Then you can use a [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm): Keep three states with a Boolean value and a time in a priority queue ordered by the times; in each step take the upcoming item from the queue and flip its Boolean value; if all three Boolean values are true, terminate; else add either the gap or the fill length to the item, depending on its Boolean value, and insert it back into the queue.

Comment: I'd like the idea, but unfortunately the first complete overlap could be very distant--in fact infinite, so efficiency is pretty important.